# What config when controller is other folder and template path is inadequate

Tags: symfony, template-engine

I work with Symfony 4.2
I divided my dir structure, and every part of app is in other folder.
Ex. admin part code is in src/Admin/... 
 - src/Admin/Controller
etc.
When I set @Template in controller method symfony tell me to situate templates in templates/
But I want to it placed in teplates/Admin/
What I should change in config.
If is other solution than set every action path in @Template(...) ?

Comment: Could you provide exact error you get? And controller code with the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the docs:

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    # ...
    paths: ["%kernel.project_dir%/resources/views"]
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-templates-directory

This might also be interesting for you:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html#multiple-paths-per-namespace